# Pytest-html Customization

Tags: python, report, pytest

I am using pytest-html plugin for report generation for my test cases. I want to add a line item if the script fails. So here's my code---

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.hookwrapper
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    pytest_html = item.config.pluginmanager.getplugin('html')
    outcome = yield
    report = outcome.get_result()
    extra = getattr(report, 'extra', [])
    if report.when == 'call':
        # always add url to report
        extra.append(pytest_html.extras.url('http://www.example.com/'))
        xfail = hasattr(report, 'wasxfail')
        if (report.skipped and xfail) or (report.failed and not xfail):
            # only add additional html on failure
            extra.append(pytest_html.extras.html('<div>Additional HTML</div>'))
        report.extra = extra

def test_sayHello():

        assert False, "I mean for this to fail"
        print "hello"


def test_sayBye():
        print "Bye"


I am running the scipt using -
 pytest --html=report.html
```

I can see the report getting generatesd but it doesnt have a line item as Additional HTML.

Also is there a way via which I can add such line items in between of my scripts to the report.

Really appreciate help.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
@pytest.mark.hookwrapper
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    pytest_html = item.config.pluginmanager.getplugin('html')
    outcome = yield
    report = outcome.get_result()
    extra = getattr(report, 'extra', [])
    if report.when == 'call':
        extra.append(pytest_html.extras.html('<p>some html</p>'))
        report.extra = extra
```